# Firebase Analytics, can't mark purchase event as conversion

Tags: firebase, xamarin, firebase-analytics

I'm logging purchase event in my Andorid and iOS app - it's build in Xamarin.
But I can't mark the event as a conversion, why?

[image]

Hope someone can help :)

Answer (score 1):

It is already marked as a convertion by default. Thats why the switch seems disabled, but it's actually switched on.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Certain events are "default" conversion events and are **always ON**. Therefore, there is no need to enable them. See the documentation here:  [Firebase documentation](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317518?hl=en#zippy=%2Cin-this-article).

It states that:

```
In Analytics, your most important events are called conversions, five of which are predefined:

 - first_open
 - in_app_purchase
 - app_store_subscription_convert
 - app_store_subscription_renew
 - purchase
```